# How to implement kubectl rollout status by calling API

Tags: javascript, kubernetes

I'm using k8s javascript sdk to restart deployment.  For restarting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284664/how-to-restart-kubernetes-deployment-using-api-server) gives a way to call API.  Now I want to check the restart status, is there any existing API for me to get the status like I use `kubectl rollout status -w deployment/some-of-my-deployments`?  I can get the deployment, but the status property is always `True` even it's being restarted.

```js
    "status": {
        "availableReplicas": 1,
        "conditions": [
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2022-10-06T04:21:12Z",
                "lastUpdateTime": "2022-10-06T04:21:12Z",
                "message": "Deployment has minimum availability.",
                "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Available"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2022-10-06T03:50:13Z",
                "lastUpdateTime": "2022-10-19T08:19:44Z",
                "message": "",
                "reason": "ReplicaSetUpdated",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Progressing"
            }
        ],
        "observedGeneration": 11,
        "readyReplicas": 1,
        "replicas": 2,
        "unavailableReplicas": 1,
        "updatedReplicas": 1
    }
```